# Is it fine to have an account to represent a company?

Tags: discussion, support

I'm working in an IT company mostly working on web applications. My company suggested to open a Stack Exchange account for our company where we'll be asking questions if any.

So my question is: Is Stack Exchange valid for companies or groups or should it be just an individual thing?

Answer (score 6):

As far as the 'mechanics' of the site go - this is *incompatible* with the TOS

> Subscriber certifies to Stack Exchange that Subscriber is an
>   individual (i.e., not a corporate entity) at least 13 years of age. No
>   one under the age of 13 may provide any personal information to or on
>   Stack Exchange (including, for example, a name, address, telephone
>   number or email address). Subscriber also certifies that they are
>   legally permitted to use the Services and access the Network, and
>   takes full responsibility for the selection and use of the Services
>   and access of the Network.

Essentially a user is a *person* not an *organisation*.

However there's nothing stopping people at your company from doing support and asking questions on the network on personal accounts- taking into account, of course the usual rules on self promotions and such. A few users include their employers in their profiles and usernames to make it clearer.

However a company wide account is not a great idea especially taking into account how the reputation system is designed to work. There's been a few experiments - like [teams](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308601/the-goal-of-teams-our-follow-up-to-your-questions) for *organisations* but this didn't quite work out.

So personal accounts with optional profiles and usernames with references to your company will be best *especially* if your goal here is primarily to ask questions.

If you also want to do support, you will also want full disclosure of affliation in your profile and posts (and those users using the site other than for support)